# Black spots... Blender Guru Tutorial - Anvil

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I did the tutorial of BLender Guru about the anvil but I am close to getting crazy due to some black spots I can not get rid of...

Render Preview:
[image: normal preview render]
Final Render:
[image: final render]
I hope this is an obvious one... Thanks for looking into it.

Nodes:
[image: Nodes]

Normalmap:
[image]

[Goodle Drive Blender File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_NDafHRsggvbpi7MkkQEQSxWV3lWcvd4)

Comment: Are the normals OK? Or maybe some duplicated overlaping faces...

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but...I recalculated the normals and checked about the overlapping faces. When Iget rid of the black metal material the black spots vanish. So i think it has something to do with normal map or displacement... :-( heeeeelp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there is **an object hidden in the viewport but not to the render engine**. Both objects have approximately the same shape and overlap each other at some parts. The node setup and baked map is perfectly fine.

Here's how you disable rendering the viewport-invisible object:
[image: deactivate rendering for an object]

Comment: Wo I am sooooo thankful and feel soooo stupid.... :-) I searched for hours... Thanks everyone for helping!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you want to mix shaders with different normals like that. The point of the Principled Node is to eliminate the need for mixing or adding shaders together. The surface of your material should only have one normal, and all other properties should be done with mix nodes before going into the principled node. For example, that "polished" map should probably be used to determine the roughness of the material, instead of mixing between two shaders.

Comment: Thank you! but... Blender Guru himself has the exact same node setup. they are the same displacment and normal map but with different (math/multiply) strength. As I said... I get crazy over this... :-)

Comment: Take a look at Your normal map.. are there orange, yellow and green “islands” if so take a look at the “how to bake perfect normals” anvil video at about 7.30

Comment: Thank you! - but... Blender Guru mentioned this problem while baking as well. normal map = fine.

Comment: Okay that looks like the error is not the normal map! Could you post the .blend file to take a look?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_NDafHRsggvbpi7MkkQEQSxWV3lWcvd4